# Dynamic loading and unloading of jar

Tags: java, jar, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

We have a java based (jersey+grizzly) REST Server which exposes calls like 

foo.com/{game}/rules

foo.com/{game}/players

foo.com/{game}/matches

There can be arbitrary number of games

Each game has different implementations for rules, players, matches

For historical reasons, we would want separate jars for each game implementation

So there is REST Server

as and when there is a call like foo.com/tennis/rules

we want the REST Server to dynamically load 'tennis' jar. The jar does its operation. Then jar should be unloaded

If the next call was for foo.com/football/players
we want the REST Server to dynamically load 'football' jar. The jar does its operation. Then jar should be unloaded

Is there a technique to do this ?

Apparently there is a very old question around [this]: [java: is there a framework that allows dynamically loading and unloading of jars (but not osgi)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603012/java-is-there-a-framework-that-allows-dynamically-loading-and-unloading-of-jars)

Comment: See URLClassLodaer API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html, simply create new instance of loader to unload jar (class garbage collection should be enabled too to avoid memory leaks )

Comment: An own ClassLoader under Java 8 might should have a better garbage collection behaviour.Everytime restarting the JVM is best. **OSGi** certainly is a solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works on Java 8, but unloading a class in Java 7 requires unloading not only the class, but its loader, along with all references from other objects that this class might have.

Once all of them were unloaded the System.gc will be called. If other classes are still holding references then the gc won't do its job.

OSGI (as suggested by @Joop Eggen) is a viable option. JRebel, is not.

Answer (score 0):

**proxy-object** [proxy-object library](https://github.com/avinokurov/proxy-object/blob/master/README.md#proxy-object)

Load java jar files dynamically in isolated class loader to avoid dependency conflicts and enable modular updates. All jar files in the [main jar folder]/lib/myLib/2.0/*.jar will be loaded.

**Code Examples**

Create Object from a JAR file located in the myLib/2.0 folder:

```
    File libDir = new File("myLib/2.0");

    ProxyCallerInterface caller = ObjectBuilder.builder()
            .setClassName("net.proxy.lib.test.LibClass")
            .setArtifact(DirArtifact.builder()
                    .withClazz(ObjectBuilderTest.class)
                    .withVersionInfo(newVersionInfo(libDir))
                    .build())
            .build();
    String version = caller.call("getLibVersion").asString();
```